# Firefox does not play some mp3 files in "audio" tag on Ubuntu

Tags: html, firefox, audio, mp3, google-translate

I am trying to play Google Translate audio mp3 files in Firefox/Ubuntu. It does not work.
A sample mp3 file is here:

http://filebin.ca/2md0ufCTcbfd/test.mp3

It plays fine within the player, but it won't play in Firefox. The error message is:

Media resource test.mp3 could not be decoded. test.html
All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.

What is wrong with the file and how can I make it play on Firefox? Do I need to install any package? Thanks in advance.

Edit: here is a sample mp3 which works:

http://filebin.ca/2mdGOjZR0ri3/test2.mp3

Comment: You have no plugin for MP3 for Firefox in Ubuntu. Try to install plugin, example : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mp3-player-1/

Comment: Edit: It plays OK most of the MP3 in audio tag. Even in Google Translate, it would play if the language is for example Greek or Chinese, but it won't play English or German.

Comment: @Momo: Was it always an MP3 file then? I bet Google Translate delivers audio in other formats too, because not all browser installations support MP3 files. Firefox, for instance, is not guaranteed to support it.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen: The only difference I see is that the attached one which does not work has a sample rate of 24kHz, while the one which works has a sample rate of 22.05kHz. I have installed all kind of gstreamers (good, bad, ugly). They are supposed to make Firefox support MP3's